# Pygame giving architecture error

Tags: python, pygame

[image: Error]

Hi I am trying to get pygame to work but I am getting an architecture problem. Is this because I am on a 64bit Mac. I have checked that base.so is in the framework library as it suggests. Using Python 2.7.5 and my mac is fully up to date with OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled Python (all versions) reinstalled Python 2.7.3 Intsalled pip then everything else. Now all is working well.